# TextView cutting off large amount of text?

Tags: xcode, storyboard

I'm currently placing my textview onto my storyboard but when I place some text inside the field it cuts off a portion of the text. It looks like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aayhn.png)

Now i've made sure there is plenty of space in my storyboard for the text so it seems really silly for this to be happening.

Why is this happening and what can I do about it? I thought about just adding another textview to solve the issue but it seems rather silly to add another object just to display another portion of uneditable text.